# IIS not running application on all bindings

Tags: .net, iis, https, binding

I've got a dotnet app running in IIS 8. I have 4 bindings, an http .com, http .local, https .com, and https .local. I have self signed certificates for .com and .local (although it seems I can only set both bindings to the same certificate at a time, which is a separate issue I think).

Anyway, I'm wanting the app to run on https .local, but it seems to be running on the https .com and NOT .local. The https .local 404s and I cannot seem to figure out how to switch the app over. Any tips?

Comment: Please run a report and attach it to this question, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html That saves others lots of time understanding your setup.

Comment: According to your description,we couldn't understand your description clearly. Do you mean you couldn't access web application by using the https .local domain and it throw the 404 page not found error?Could you please post more details information about the binding setting? You could post a caputre image for us to better understand your question.